# MySQL - PHP - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'myproject'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm very new to PHP so please bear with me. I have a registration form and I'm submitting the values entered on that form and having them inserted into  a MySQL Database table, but I'm getting the following error:

ErrorAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'myproject'

I've granted all the access that is possible to the user that I'm using in my code, but I'm still having this error. Any help is appreciated and points will be awarded!

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>Registration Page</title>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["netID"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("NetID must be filled out");
    return false;
    }

    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("Email must be filled out");
    return false;
    }

    var n = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (n == null || n == "") {
    alert("First Name cannot be blank");
    return false;
    } else if (n.length < 2) {
        alert("First name cannot be less than 2 characters!");
        return false;
    }

    var b = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
    if (b == null || b == "") {
    alert("Last Name cannot be blank");
    return false;
    } else if (b.length < 2) {
        alert("Last Name cannot b less than 2 characters!");
        return false;

    }

}

</script>



</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <center><img src="KSUlogo.PNG" alt="logo" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</ul>


<h1 style="text-align:center;">CCSE Community Profile Page</h1>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<h2 style="text-align:center;">Enter your Registration Information</h2>

<div style="text-align:center">

<form name="myForm" action="RegistrationValues.php" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<center>NetID: <input type="text" name="netID"></center>
<br>
<center>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></center>
<br>
<center>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"></center>
<br>
<center>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"></center>
<br>
<br>
Services You Can Provide the CSE Community</center><br>
<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="Java"> Java Tutoring<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="Computer" checked> Computer Fixing<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="PHP" checked> PHP Tutoring<br>
<br><br>
<select name="availabilty">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="Java">Morning</option>
    <option value="Computer">Evening</option>
    <option value="Service">Afternoon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
</form>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>Registration Page</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php include "header.html";?>
<?php include "navigation.html";?>

<div style="text-align:center">

<p>netID: <?php echo $_POST["netID"]?></p>

<p>Email: <?php echo $_POST["email"]?></p>

<p>First Name <?php echo $_POST["fname"]?></p>

<p>Last Name: <?php echo $_POST["lname"]?></p>

<?php

$netID = $email = $fname = $lname = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $netID = test_input($_POST["netID"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
  $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "newpassword";
$dbname = "myproject";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die( 'Error'. mysql_error() );
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysql_query("insert into ProfileInformation (netID, email, fname, lname, radio, availabilty) 
values
  ('$_POST[netID]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[radio]','$_POST[availabilty]')")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Done!!!!";


$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>


</body>
</html>
```

It seems to be reading '' as a username somewhere but I'm not sure though.
Thanks in advance. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` is the problem

Comment: Thanks. What is your suggestion on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick one api and use it rather than mix n match - however, saying that it would be better to use prepared statements rather than embedding the `$_POST` variables directly in the sql. Incidentally the names within $_POST need to be quoted unless they exist as constants!

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$conn->query("insert into ProfileInformation (netID, email, fname, lname, radio, availabilty) 
                values
            ( '{$_POST['netID']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['fname']}', '{$_POST['lname']}', '{$_POST['radio']}', '{$_POST['availabilty']}' )") or die(mysql_error());

            echo "Done!!!!";

$conn->close();
```

---

Now that you have the issue of the connection sorted ( btw - what was the issue? You should perhaps share the reason it was failing for future readers ) the sql you presented initially is vulnerable to sql injection. The preferred method would be to use a `prepared statement` like the following:

```
if( isset( $_POST['netID'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['radio'], $_POST['availabilty'] ) ) {


    $host   =   'localhost';
    $uname  =   'xxx'; 
    $pwd    =   'xxx'; 
    $db     =   'xxx';

    $conn   =   new mysqli( $host, $uname, $pwd, $db );

    if ( !$conn ) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
    }


    $sql='insert into `ProfileInformation` ( `netID`, `email`, `fname`, `lname`, `radio`, `availabilty` ) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,? );';
    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){

        $netid=$_POST['netID'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $radio=$_POST['radio'];
        $avail=$_POST['availabilty'];

        /*
            use i for integers
            use s for strings
        */
        $stmt->bind_params( 'isssss', $netid,$email,$fname,$lname,$radio,$avail );
        $result=$stmt? 'Success!' : 'Fail!';

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();

    } else {
        echo 'Error creating statement';
    }
} else {
    echo 'One or more required POST variables are not set';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same error:
ErrorAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'myproject'

Comment: As suggested by @Pradyut Manna ~ check your db connection details - notably the user and confirm that user exists in the db as a valid user

Comment: I did and the user does exist as a valid user in the database.

Comment: and ALL PRIVILEGES set as global privileges?

Comment: And does that user have the necessary permissions to read/write to the db?

Comment: Yes the User has ALL PRIVILLEGES and that user can read/write to the db. Please help Thanks

Comment: Do you have anymore suggestions? I'm still stuck on this.

Comment: Ok the access error is resolved, but now the data is not being inserted into the database.

Answer (score 1):

check your phpmyadmin. The user **myUser** and password **newpassword** that you used i think this is not exists.go phpmyadmin->user Accounts and check.you can try to do this:-

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myproject";
```

Comment: I got

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\IndividualProject\RegistrationValues.php on line 51
ErrorAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'myproject'

Comment: then check your phpmyadmin ->useraccounts the user list.

Comment: I did. I've been able to use other users to insert data into a database, but now I'm getting this error. Please help thanks

Comment: No no i mean mysql user not your table user

Comment: I did and the mysql user is a valid user. I think there is an error in my code that I'm not checking because I'm so new to PHP